# Is Android Studio supported on Mac OS 10.15 (Catalina)?

Tags: android, android-studio, macos-catalina

I am about to upgrade from Mojave to Catalina on my Macbook Pro, as I need to install the latest version of Xcode for an iOS project, which requires Catalina.  However, I also am working on an Android project, and as such, need Android Studio to run stably.  So I am left wondering, does Android Studio run on Catalina?  I have heard conflicting reports on this, and developers having issues running it. Also, on the Android Studio system requirements page, it states

**Mac® OS X® 10.10 (Yosemite) or higher, up to 10.14 (macOS Mojave)**

https://developer.android.com/studio

This seems to imply that it either does not run or is not supported.  Can anyone verify this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Zero problems for me. Simulator works, debugging works.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and glad to hear that there are no problems.  Just kind of strange that Android's own documentation would state "up to 10.14 (macOS Mojave)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no problem so far, everything works as before the update. I have Android Studio 4.0.

[image]

Comment: x2, I have no problem in my case, macOs Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: Thank you for your responses, and glad to hear that there are no problems.  Just kind of strange that Android's own documentation would state "up to 10.14 (macOS Mojave)."

Comment: I tried to download 4.1.1 in Catalina. It installs fine, but gets stuck opening. Tried everything and it won't open. I was able to install and open 4.0.2 just fine, luckily.

Answer (score 3):

version 4.1 does not work on Mac OS catalina. We hope for an update for the moment it is possible to use only the 4.0.x versions
from here you can choose the android studio versions that suit your needs.
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive
Also if you have switched from Mac OS sierra to catalina you may have problems configuring ruby for flutter, in this case the argument is much longer but a workaround is to use default ruby as illustrated here:
https://rvm.io/rubies/default

Comment: Android Studio site now claims support for Mojave and higher. https://developer.android.com/studio#system-requirements-a-namerequirementsa (scroll to the bottom)